# How to prevent a hacker accessing user session from outside?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, security, session

We have a website that use CodeIgniter. We use Facebook SDK to connect and store the token in a session variable. We have controller functions that are called by AJAX code and create entry in our data base. But to create the entry a session variable should be valid.

Recently someone found a way to attack us and pretend that he has a valid session and call these functions and create many data base entries in our website. We are now forced to close the website to make some change to prevent that.

But we are not PHP programmers, we are C/C++ programmers and don't know how the person did that. We know that he used curl library 7.43.0.

Can someone help us please to correct our code? By the way we are not a HTTPS website.

Here is the session configuration for CodeIgniter:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1800;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 60;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Here is cookies configuration:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'liftoffre_';
$config['cookie_domain']    = $domain;
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Here is the code we use to verify a session before creating an entry on database:

```
public function create_offer()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('token') != null)
    {
        $titre = "Nouvelle offre";

        $data = array(
            'userGraph' => $this->session->userdata('userData'),
            'titre' => $titre
        );

        $this->load->view('nouvelle_offre', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/main/');
    }
}

public function ajouter_offre()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('token') != null) {
        $data = array(
            'offre_departure_name' => $this->input->post('offre_departure_name', TRUE),
            'offre_departure_adresse' => $this->input->post('offre_departure_adresse', TRUE),
            'offre_departure_province' => $this->input->post('offre_departure_province', TRUE),
            'offre_departure_city' => $this->input->post('offre_departure_city', TRUE),
            'offre_arrival_name' => $this->input->post('offre_arrival_name', TRUE),
            'offre_arrival_adresse' => $this->input->post('offre_arrival_adresse', TRUE),
            'offre_arrival_province' => $this->input->post('offre_arrival_province', TRUE),
            'offre_arrival_city' => $this->input->post('offre_arrival_city', TRUE),
            'offre_datetime' => $this->input->post('offre_datetime', TRUE),
            'offre_price' => $this->input->post('offre_price', TRUE),
            'offre_seats_number' => $this->input->post('offre_seats_number', TRUE),
            'offre_userid' => $this->input->post('offre_userid', TRUE),
            'offre_commentaire' => $this->input->post('offre_commentaire', TRUE),

        );

        $this->load->model('Datasource');
        $this->Datasource->add_offer($data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/main/');
    }
}
```

These two function can be called by using a POST method and calling link like domain.com/index.php/controller/function.

Here a log from the server

```
209.222.7.236 - - [27/Jun/2016:06:50:33 -0700] "POST /index.php/nouvelleoffre/ajouter_offre/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.43.0"
```

Does someone know how to help us?

Comment: Do you use session cookies? If you do, do you renew the session id e.g every request? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation

Comment: We use functions that CodeIgniter give us, so we thought it should do the work, but I don't know how can I confirm that information

Comment: But does that means that the hacker used a existent session or he used another trick to that.

Comment: When a session is created, it gets an id. If you do not renew that id, someone can manually create a session with the same id, and get interpreted by the server as the user.

Comment: I don't use codeigniter myself, but i think they should have thought about that.

Comment: Otherwise do you have SSL protection?

Comment: Where can I find the session ID, do you know how to do that with CodeIgniter

Comment: Like I said in my article our website is not SSL, but i'm pretty sure that we should have a way to do it wihout SSL

Comment: The question is why don't you use SSL, it's almost a necessity novadays. If you're not using it because it's costly there's a new free ssl provider: https://letsencrypt.org/.

Comment: But if I use SSL does SSL will prevent a person to access a session ?

Comment: Can he do things like that even with SSL?

Comment: Does the way we verify session is the correct Way ?

Comment: The issue with not using ssl is that someone can divert the traffic of the user through his computer, just like you would hook up to a telephone line and listen to everything that goes through it. But you can't so easily if the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: I'm almost certainly positive the issue is with not using ssl, but we must consider everything.

Comment: It is really hard to get the session id without intercepting traffic.  If someone accesses your site on an open WiFi network, it is extremely easy to hijack sessions, since the session id is sent with every request. You can regenerate the session id more often, but this won't help if someone is snooping.  SSL is really hard (though not impossible) to crack, this is why it is required by banking, commerce, etc sites.

Comment: activate csrf protection and generate the key every request.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter, though unarguably one of the best PHP frameworks to be developed, had a problem of not properly storing sessions, i.e. it was noted for storing the SESSION data in the COOKIE, only in encrypted format. Thus with sufficient knowledge about your system and the hashing algorithm used, an attacker could've transformed all cookie data to session data. This problem was solved, however before CodeIgniter v3 was released.
But I believe the best way to store sessions may be:
1. Do not autoload the session class, but rather load them whenever you need them.
2. Define a basepath or exit, i.e. `defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed')`
3. Though an overstretch, I recommend setting an encryption key and encrypting every session value before you store it (remember to set a strong encryption key password)